# Is it good idea to write API Call within Appium script for automation

Tags: java, automation, appium-android, appium-ios

I am working with Appium with Java for iOS and Android as one repo. My question is is it good idea to make API call within Appium script.
Here is my case
I have different status like accepted, Pending, In_porgress, null etc.
So for every status I want to execute API call and then verify status on client side. (This API is over Bluetooth and all state cann't capture from client/mobile side)

Please advice if I can make API call within the script?

Answer (score 0):

In my iOS automation testing i create APICall for some scenario, is working properly and can reduce flaky